# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I've been looking for this answer and the other pages didn't help me.

I'm trying to use the google drive api for php. I am trying to test on my local environment and receive this error.

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob did not match a registered    redirect URI



Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
response_type=code
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
access_type=offline
display=page

prompt=consent
client_id=735129338633-0epug8n80jsg0t50ijn7our4a661nnk6.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Here is the page for the api:

The url is in 
      localhost:8888/Spreadsheets/driver.php

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you putting `redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` in your query string, when you really want to redirect to `localhost:8888/Spreadsheets/driver.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the current Google OAuth2 integration requires enabling

```
Contacts API
Google+ API
```

from the Google Developers Console for the associated Project. In my log I noticed errors liek `403, Access Not Configured. Please use ....`

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI (where the response is returned to) has to be correct and exactly as you registered in the APIs console, and the error is indicating that you haven't done that or you haven't done it correctly.

To get the redirect URI from console:

1. Go to the console for your project and look under API Access.
2. Open Credentials section (in left side)
3. You should see your client ID & secret there, along with there is a
   list of redirect URIs. If you want to change it or it was wrong,
   click edit settings and modify.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your redirect uri is properly set in the console, a lot of times, when you've recently changed settings in the google dev console, it will still tell you there's a redirect mismatch.  It's a surprisingly common occurrence.

You can try...

- Waiting; some have had luck with this, indicating that google takes some amount of time to register recent changes.
- If you don't mind reconfiguring your app, creating a new client id in the google dev console tends to fix this problem with consistent results.